# Why splitting ajax data works in console but not in page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am loading content with ajax and want to split by a custom tag,

it does not work in page, but it does work in console

here is the function

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < propsPDF.length; i++){

    divProp = crearContenedorProp(i);
    $("#contenedorPDF").append(divProp);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "inc/tem.asp",
      data: {tipo: propsPDF[i][0], codigo: propsPDF[i][1], suc: propsPDF[i][2]},
      success: function(data) {

                var partes = data.split("<pagebreak />");
                alert(partes.length);

            },
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
      dataType: 'html'

    });
}
```

the html loaded is a normal HTML page with a custom tag     used to specify pagebreak in mPDF PHP library used to convert html to pdf

Comment: So when running from console you see the split and length you expect?  What do you get when it runs in a browser?

Comment: yes, i
n console I get 3 that is what I expect. But in browser I get 1...

Comment: It's hard to know what's causing this since there could be many other things going on in the page...I'd recommend testing it with a simple page that contains only the `contenedorPDF` div and a `<script>` tag with a `$(document).ready()` callback and then building the page up from there and see when it breaks.